# What exactly does Watts and dB signify?

Tags: audio, amplifier, speakers

Now this is confusing.
At some point i read that higher watts does not neccesarily signify high volume sound. An amp rated at 100w and other rated at 50w dows not mean the former is 2 times louder. Only slightly loud by 3dB which is nothing. To make the latter twice as loud, i should pump the wattage 10x.

Now there is also one thing to consider. SPL.
If i connect a lower SPL speaker to 100w amp and a higher SPL speaker to the 50w amp, the 50w amp will be actually louder than 100w.

Now you tell me, if I am designing an amp, what Wattage amp am i supposed to make. All the time i was looking looking for a 200w ic. After all this literature i went thru, I can also do with a 15w ic and connect a high SPL rating speaker to it. That will suffice?

What does the amp Watt actually tell me?
When am i suppose to use a higher or lower watt amp?
What does it mean to the battery, and speaker?
And ultimately to the listener?

And talking about speakers, i also read somewhere a high end speaker has more impedance than a low end one. Most of the ic datasheet lists for a low impedance ones' - 4ohm. All the while i thought the amp was powerful enuf to drive such speakers? So for high impedance it wont be useful?

Comment: This is too broad to answer. Can you focus this question down to your real problem. For instance you ask "When am i suppose to use a higher or lower watt amp" - how can anyone answer this question!! Also the subject of listener tests and subjective tests is very wide. You also make statements like "high end speakers have more impedance" - where do you read this and where is the link?

Comment: "what Wattage amp am i supposed to make" - are you trying to fill a concert hall or drive a pair of headphones? For home use in one room, even 15W per channel will be perfectly adequate with a set of normal 8 ohm speakers; for some classical music with a very high dynamic range you may want to go up to 50-100W per channel.

Answer (score 2):

### What are Decibel?

Decibel are a measurement of power. It can be calculated by the following formula:

$$a_{db} = 10*log(\frac{P}{P_0})$$

Decibel is a measurement that is **relative**, which means it always has a **reference**. Usually this reference is 1 milliwatt and the pseudounit is "dbm". The unit is a pseudounit because there can't be any units inside of mathematical functions such as the logarithm.

There are several suffixes and all vary in their reference:

dbm is referenced to 1mW, so P_0 is 0,001W.

dbW is referenced to 1W, so P_0 is 1W.

db is referenced to some power level you measure somewhere. This is used for amplifiers to quickly determine what gain they have (Output power referenced to the input power).

Keep in mind that there are **only measurements of power**!

Now we often see units like dbµ and dbV. The assumption there is that P=U^2/R and if R1 equals R2 they cancel out (as do the voltages!):

$$a_  {dbµ} = 10*log(\frac{P}{P_0}) = 10*log(\frac{\frac{U_1^2}{R_1}}{\frac{U_2^2}{R_2}}) =10*log(\big(\frac{U_1*R_2}{U_2*R_1}\big)^2)= 20*log(\frac{U_1*R_2}{U_2*R_1}) \\ = 20*log(\frac{U_1}{U_2})$$

The reference would be µV and V.

### Why do we use Decibel?

In communications engineering we often need to draw diagrams of signal strength and Bode plots for filters. Now imagine a usual GSM base station which is transmitting with 1Watt and therefore 30dbm. The attenuation is usually the factor 1000000000 (90db) or more. So your mobile has to work with signal strengths as low as 30dbm-90dbm = -60dbm which equals 0.000001mW.

Ten decibel is (thanks to the logarithm) an amplification/attenuation of one decade (multiplication/division by 10). That means you make huge numbers very small and you can draw a diagram of signal strengths or Bode plots for filters without going from 0.0000000mW to 100000000W. Another benefit is that we can add and subtract the decibel instead of multiplicating the numbers which is a feature derived from the logarithmic calculus:

100dbm = 10 Megawatt
-50dbm = 0.0000001 Watt

### Your specific usecase

The wattage on your amplifier tells you how loud in reference to how silent it can be. The reference here is the noise-floor your amplifier has (every component is noisy! Even resistors!) in comparison to the maximum it can do. this is called dynamic range and calculated by 
$$10*log(\frac{P_{100\%}}{P_{0\%}})$$

The higher the dynamic range the higher is its output power or the lower the noisefloor.
Another thing that this tells you is the approximate power level your speaker should be rated for.

You are supposed to use a higher power amp when your audience is very big, eg at concerts. 4 times the power equals 2 times the volume (same speakers provided). 150Watt is a very big amplifier in a room if you have decent loudspeakers (not the cheap ones from the grocery store). A higher wattage also means that the amp will drain your battery a lot faster (this is linear. 100W amps the battery twice as fast as the same amp with 50W output). The speaker receives - of course - a larger amount of power and therefore displaces more. You can crank the volume up until the speaker or the amplifier is at it's limit (audible crackling noises).

All in all the listener determines  6db as approximately twice the loudness at which you need to provide 4 times the power to achieve it.

My opinion is that you rather should look out for a speaker with a high efficiency (the enclosure is also an important factor!) and a smaller amplifier.

Comment: The statement "... Ten decibel is (thanks to the logarithm) an amplification/attenuation of ten decades (10^10) ..." is incorrect - as I think you know. You may wish to change it to read what you wished to actually say. (I did not try to edit this as I may misinterpret your point).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out. I'd also like to thank you for the other corrections you made to my post: Dezibel is the german word for decibel and I constantly keep falling back to it.

Answer (score 1):

WOW. You have asked a lot of questions.  I understand your confusion because I suffered from the same confusion.  I have figured some of it out and will try to answer some it.

1) db are on a logarithmic scale which is necessary because of the energy required to produce sound.  It takes such a ridiculous amount of power to produce the loudness of a rock concert vs the volume of a conversation that the numbers you would be using would be 10 to the power of 12 vs maybe 1000.  Just crazy and difficult to manage.  Using the logarithmic scale keeps the numbers on an easy scale, once you understand how to use the scale.  like you said, increasing by 3db is doubling the power output, increasing the sound by 10bd requires 10x the power.

2) SPL of the speaker. I think what you are referring to is what most speaker manufacturers call sensitivity.  They measure it using - you guessed it - db!  You are correct, if you got a speaker with a higher sensitivity, it takes less power to make it go louder.  Unfortunately, this is limited in the fact that most speakers out there have a sensitivity that is between 80-100, so it would make a difference, but not necessarily a big difference.  Generally speaking, the difference in sensitivity between 2 speakers is not enough that it would make one speaker significantly louder than another on a more powerful amp.  Your example of the 50w amp vs the 100w amp and the sensitivity of the speakers might actually make the 50w amp sound louder - I have never heard of that in real life.

3) Impedance- complicated.  "Most high end speakers have higher impedance" - wrong.  You can't generalize it like that.  High end speakers are usually somewhere between 4 and 8 ohms (actually most speakers are between 4 and 8 ohms, some car subwoofers are at 2ohm and some small computer speakers at 16ohms).  My understanding from the "HiFi" magazines, is that the lower impedance speakers are the harder ones on the amps and the ones requiring more powerful amps.

4) What wattage should my amp be?  Up to you and all of those factors.  Don't forget about your room.  The sound level (db level) will drop 6db for every time you DOUBLE the distance from the speakers.   So if your amp and speaker combo give you 80db at 2 feet, they will give you 74db at 4 feet, 68 db at 8 feet etc.
Generally speaking, a higher wattage amp is a good idea.  If you don't have to push your amp at full power to get the volume you want is better for the amp and tends to give better sound than running your amp at max.

Hope this helps!